# If statements inside a for loop over lines in a file

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, lines, text-processing

I have a file `data.txt`:

```
./path1
 * WITH LDLDLDLDLDLD                 *
  KDKDKDKDKD
  LDLDLDLDLDLDLDLD
  LDFLFLFLFLFLFLF
['-2.6993']
['-2.6983']
['-2.4490']
  LSLSLSLSLSL
['-2.6993']
['-2.6983']
['-2.4490']
  KKKGKGKGKGKGKGKG
['-79.7549']
  LDLDLDLDLDLDLDLDL
['-126.6208']
['-93.9881']
  KDKDKDKDKDKDKDKD
['-156.9296']
['-135.3548']
  LDLDLDLDDLDDLDLDLD
['-178.3941']
['-162.8602']
['-42.7064']
  KDKDKDKDKDLDLDLDLDLD
['-193.3335']
['-181.9782']
['-68.6555']

./path2
 * WITH DLLDLDLDLDLLDLD                 *
  LDLDLDLDLDLDLD
  BEBEBEBEBEBEL
  LSLSLSLSLSLSL
['-2.6993']
['-2.6983']
['-2.4490']
  OSOSOSOSOSOSOSOS
['-2.6993']
['-2.6983']
['-2.4490']
  KDKDKDKDKDKDKDKDKD
['-156.9296']
['-135.3548']
  MDMDMDMDMDMDDMDM
['-178.3941']
['-162.8602']
['-42.7064']
  KFKFKFKFPKLDLDLD
['-193.3335']
['-181.9782']
['-105.4751']
['-96.2342']
```

From which I would like to print the `path` and the negative values on that path.

The following code achieves this goal:

```
import re
import os
import numpy as np

f = open('data.txt', 'r')
All_aux = []

for line in f:
         if re.match(r"^\.", line):
          print line

         if re.match(r"^\[", line):

                 target2 = line.translate(None, "[]'',")    
                 aux = target2.split()
                 All_aux.append(aux)
                 flat_list = [item for sublist in All_aux for item in sublist]

print 'len(negatives) = ' , len(flat_list)
```

But the information printed is the following:

```
./path1

./path2

len(negatives) =  32
```

Once the first `if re.match(r"^\.", line):` is matched, it prints the line, but it does not print the first 17 negative values. Instead, this value is saved and summed to the 15 negative values found on the 2nd path.

I would like to obtain the following:

```
./path1

len(negatives) =  17

./path2

len(negatives) =  15
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe print and reset the negatives within the loop `if line.startswith("./"):`?

Comment: @cdarke Thanks for your comment, I apologise but I do not understand what you mean by print and reset the negatives within the if loop. Would it be possible if you could give more details ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I meant by the comment.  I have made a few other improvements as well, for example using a string method which is generally simpler and more efficient than a regular expression.

After a little thought and discussion with @tripleee I have dispensed with the `flat_list` since all you were doing is counting the length.

I have commented, but please ask if you don't understand anything:

```
# None of the imports are required
# We only need a count
negatives = 0

# Previously you were not closing the file
# This closes it automagically
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # No need for a regular expression here
        if line.startswith("./"):
            if negatives:
                print 'len(negatives) = ' , negatives, '\n'
                negatives = 0
            print line

        # Used "else if" since both `startswith` can't be true
        elif line.startswith("["):
            target2 = line.translate(None, "[]'',")
            # simplified
            negatives += len(target2.split())

if negatives:
    print 'len(negatives) = ' , negatives
```

This gives:

```
./path1

len(negatives) =  17

./path2

len(negatives) =  15
```

Comment: The `flat_list` processing is still kind of ugly and inefficient.  If you simply do `flat_list.extend(target2.split())` there is no need to separately flatten the result (let alone do it over and over inside the innermost loop, or keep the `aux` variables).

Comment: @tripleee: I agree, I was thinking of refactoring that.

Comment: Thinking about it, I don't think we even need `flat_list`, only a count.

Comment: Indeed! (-: Go for it.

Comment: @cdarke Thanks a lot for your answer. It took me a while to understand each step. I had to break into multiple steps. I think I have now understood all the bits and pieces. Thanks again.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks a lot for your suggestion on the `flat_list`